# Why does my iPad want to store my access code in iCloud?

Tags: ios, apple-id

Today, after restarting my iPad running iOS 14.8 a prompt appeared telling me to re-enter my access code so it can be stored in my iCloud.

Why is this necessary?

Comment: I focused the question on the problem of storing the access code in iCloud (please ask a separate question if something in the Terms bothers you). Do you have a screenshot of the message you could add?